# Is there a way to animate navigationbaritems with withAnimation(...?

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui, modifier, navigationbaritems

For some reason the SwiftUi withAnimation does not work in the navigationBarItems modifier. Is there a fix for that? I know the .animation modifier on the view that is animated works but this is not enough for more complex animations.

I was wondering that no one asked this question before, I assume more people have the issue. Does anyone know a fix for that?

One example here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d2Ud2xxhVCJBCfBQwlZ1mJgTnyNpxc_-/view?usp=sharing

````
    struct TestView: View {
    
      @State var red = true
    
      var body: some View {
        NavigationView {

            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(red ? Color.red : .blue)
                        .onTapGesture {
                         
                         
                         withAnimation(Animation.easeIn(duration: 1), {
                                
                            red.toggle()
                            })
                        }
                    
                }
                
                
                Spacer()
                
            }
            
            
                
            .navigationTitle("Test")
            .navigationBarItems(leading:
                                    HStack {
                                        Rectangle()
                                            .fill(red ? Color.red : .blue)
                                            .onTapGesture {
                                             
                                             
                                                   withAnimation(Animation.easeIn(duration: 1), {
                                                    
                                                red.toggle()
                                                })
                                            }
                                    }
                                    
            )
        }
        
       }
    }


    struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
      static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
      }
    }
    

    ```


Edit: Aspires solution is valid for my original question. For some reason it still does not work in the context I am using it in:

    struct ContentView: View {
    
    
    @State var redColor = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            
            Button("change Color", action: {
                withAnimation(Animation.easeIn(duration: 1), {
                    redColor.toggle()
                })
            })
            
            .navigationTitle("Test")
            .navigationBarItems(leading:
                                    RectView(redColor: $redColor)
            )
        }

     }
}


struct RectView: View {
    
    @State var red: Bool = false
    @Binding var redColor: Bool

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
             Rectangle()
                  .fill(red ? Color.red : .blue)
        }.onChange(of: redColor, perform: { _ in
            red.toggle()
        })
    }
}
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to separate that state dependent animatable code into standalone view, like show below.

Tested with Xcode 12.4 / iOS 14.4

[image]

```
struct TestBarAnimationView: View {

      @State var red = true

      var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                RectView(red: $red)       // << here !!
                Spacer()
            }
            .navigationTitle("Test")
            .navigationBarItems(leading:
                RectView(red: $red)       // << here !!
            )
        }

       }
    }


struct RectView: View {
    @Binding var red: Bool

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
             Rectangle()
                  .fill(red ? Color.red : .blue)
                  .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation(Animation.easeIn(duration: 1), {
                        red.toggle()
                        })
                  }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That actually solves the problem in its test environment. In the actually environment I have a state variable that triggers an animation onChange of a binding variable. For some reason this still does not work. 


.onChange(of: changeColor) { _ in
      red.toggle()
}